# Error when running conda.exe activate on WSL

Tags: linux, windows, conda, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am able to execute `conda.exe create` successfully, however `conda activate` gives me the following error.

```
CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
If using 'conda activate' from a batch script, change your
invocation to 'CALL conda.bat activate'.

To initialize your shell, run

    $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>

Currently supported shells are:
  - bash
  - cmd.exe
  - fish
  - tcsh
  - xonsh
  - zsh
  - powershell

See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.

IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.
```

As I am using WSL, which shell should I initialize?

`conda init`

Comment: UNIX distributions generally use `bash`, so try that. It's not going to hurt anything to run one that you don't use anyway. Also, if you have doubts, you can use the `-d` flag for a dry run, and a `-vv` to see what would be modified.